# Change Listview in a Fragment to horizontal without using RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview

```
View fragment_view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    List<String> datalist2 = new ArrayList<>();
    datalist2.add("FirstAid");
    datalist2.add("Login");
    datalist2.add("Profile");
    datalist2.add("Ambulance");
    datalist2.add("Medicine");
    datalist2.add("News");
    datalist2.add("HRM");

    fragment_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_bar, container, false);
    list_view_menu_adapter  adapter2=new list_view_menu_adapter (getContext(),datalist2);
    final ListView L2= (ListView) fragment_view.findViewById(R.id.menu_scroll_list);
    L2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

**How can I change this list to horizontal currently it is showing me verticaly without RecyclerView if possible**

Comment: You cant use `ListView` to show items horizontally, either you have to customize `ListView` or use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: So How to customize 'Listview'  ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView